# Can't get Imagick PHP Extension to load when building PHP from source

Tags: php, apache2, imagemagick

I've built PHP 7.4 from source, and installed ImageMagick via yum.
When I run
`convert --version` i got `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2021-02-24`
Then I ran `pecl install imagick` and it says 
 `Build process completed successfully. Installing '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so'`
I've also added `extension=imagick.so` to my `/usr/local/php/lib/php.ini` file & restarted Apache.
When I run `php -m | grep imagick` it returns `imagick`, but when I view the phpinfo() page, it's not there. I've confirmed my php-cli & phpinfo() are reading the same php.ini file from `/usr/local/php/lib/php.ini`.
Here are some screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: have you restarted your PHP-FPM/Apache httpd instance?

Comment: I've rebooted multiple times

Comment: please show us the used path and the pathes from PHP Info page, do you use any kind of admin panel?

Comment: I've added screen shots to the paths I'm assuming you're asking about. Let me know if you're asking about some other path. No Admin Panel.

Comment: did you edited php.ini and which one?

Comment: Yes, I added `extension=imagick.so` to `/usr/local/php/lib/php.ini`. New screen shot added to question.

Comment: could it be that you use the apache php module instead the local installed version?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. How would I check that & correct it?